# Notation of functional relationships in Fuzzy Logic

Tags: functions, notation, fuzzy-logic

I would like to know how to put the following ideas in to a more formal mathematical notation:

> Traditional methods implement a direct functional relationship
> between input and output signals:
>
> > > ***I'd like to insert mathematical notation that helps to formalize what I just said here***
>
> However, the new system implements an indirect relationship where the
> input signals are translated via rules into *linguistic* variables and weightings. These are then interpolated at the output according to the set of weights and other
> rules that seek to mimic the same functional relationship as the
> traditional method:
>
> > > ***Again, I'd like to insert mathematical notation that helps to formalize of what I just said here***

On a descriptive level I have a project that has elements similar to fuzzy logic*. I'm wondering how I could make a basic attempt at mathematically formalizing it.

(* the irony)

**EDIT**

Does this:

> $f: X \mapsto Y$

..apply in both cases? Or just the first?